# Should reopened posts display as "modified" by the last vote to reopen user in the active questions tab or should they have a different status?

Tags: discussion, reopened-questions

I voted to reopen a closed [post on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/399035/is-there-any-official-game-boy-catalog-of-games) and noticed that after doing so, the posts shows up in the Active questions page as being "modified" by me (the last voter of the review task):

[image: active questions post]

The [reopen privilege page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) doesn't mention this behavior. Note that I am site moderator for Arqade - I don't think this behavior is specific to moderators only, although we do have the power of single-vote reopen/close on posts (this particular post in question already had 3 other reopen votes).

If you click on the "modified 2 mins ago" link, all it does is open up the post.  This can be even more misleading because at the time of posting, the last edit was made by a different user.

Should this instead maybe say it was "reopened" rather than modified? Should it also not show a specific user (perhaps instead show the Community User)?

Comment: Originally posted as bug actually. Doesn't really matter though, it's something we want to be changed.

Comment: Oh - 8 years old this is. Wowza!

Comment: Yeah, there are even older bug reports and feature requests sitting around.

Comment: I did also try searching for a similar post, but searching on Meta SE is always difficult I find, especially when its a really old post.  Seems the common FAQ post is always the first thing returned...

Comment: Yeah took me several tries to find, [this is the winning search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22modified%22+%22reopen%22+is%3Aq). From experience, the hard part is figuring what to search for.

Comment: I'm considering for a while to start feature request that will make it more organized, but probably won't be very popular. In essence, don't show "asked", "answered", or "modified" at all, instead always show who asked, always show top 3 answerers, and timestamp of "last activity" of the question. To know what was this last activity one will just have to click it, like today, but it won't be misleading anymore. (It won't say *who* is responsible for the last activity)